# set the Value of a checkbox Asp.net MVC, Html.CheckBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my view I have the following which shows it as a checkbox:

```
<td style="padding:3px"><%= Html.CheckBox("Statistik3", (Boolean)ViewData["Statistik3"], new { @tabindex = "10" })%>     </td>
```

Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult FormularStatistikKennzeichen(string button, string decision1, FormEntries entries)
        {

if (i > 0)
            {
                ViewData["Statistik3"] = true;
            }
            if (i == 0)
            {
                ViewData["Statistik3"] = false;
            }
            i = i + 1;
}
```

in the first i can initialize the checkBox to true or false but after that
i cant change and controll the Value in the checkBox? have you any idea how

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean server- or client-side? If server-side, then you'd need to keep track of the counter in the session.  You can't use an instance variable because the controller is recreated every time a request is made, meaning it would always be zero for the request.  You can't use a static variable, unless you want to share state among users.  Even then it would be reinitialized each time the application pool recycles.  If you want the state to be persistent, then you either need to track that as part of the page state (i.e., postback the current value with the form each time) or use session state.

If you mean client-side, you should be aware that the checkbox helper will output two inputs, one a checkbox and one a hidden value with the same name and the value of false.  This is to ensure that on post of the form the checkbox has a value to map onto the a (required) boolean in your model/parameters. When updating it client-side with JavaScript, you should take care to only modify the value of the checkbox, not the hidden field, to get consistent results.

Comment: thank for your answer... it is client- side... that is just an example the value of ViewData["Statistik3"] will be set from the DB ViewData["Statistik3"] = db.getStatistkValue(); How can i only modify the value of the checkbox?

Comment: @HaifaDerouiche using jQuery it would be something like `$('[name="Statistik3"][type="checkbox"]').prop(true)` or `false` as appropriate.

Comment: must i use jQuery? is there another way how to write the checkBox in the View with the traditionel HTML like <input type="checkbox" name="Statistik3" value="<%=(Boolean)ViewData["Statistik3"] %>"/> or something in this direction

Comment: @HaifaDerouiche - you said you want to change it client-side, which implies you'd be using JavaScript. You don't have to use jQuery but jQuery makes it easier. I'm concerned we might not be talking about the same thing, though, as your example would be a *server-side* statement.

Comment: hmm.. i m a beginner and i dont know 100% what Side: The Controller code is c# and the ASPX <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %> <td style="padding:3px"><%= Html.CheckBox("Statistik3", (Boolean)ViewData["Statistik3"], new { @tabindex = "10" })%>     </td>

Comment: @HaifaDerouiche controller & view rendering is run server-side, JavaScript is run client-side.  Normally you would set the values for the view in the controller, then any dynamic changes that happen in the browser are handled via JavaScript. Changes that happen as a result of a form POST (or clicking a link aka GET request) are done by rendering a new view on the server and sending the updated view to the client.

Comment: the same Problem is discribed in this Blog http://weblogs.asp.net/ashicmahtab/archive/2009/03/27/asp-net-mvc-html-dropdownlist-and-selected-value.aspx but with the DropDownList... if i change the Name in the aspx:  <%= Html.CheckBox("markt", (Boolean)ViewData["Statistik3"], new { @tabindex = "10" })%>     </td> i can put the value every time i like but i c ant get The Value of the Checkbox anymore!